Old macadamia nuts have a bitter taste and sticky-greasy mouthfeel, is that normal?
I bought a bag of Macadamia nuts from Costco a year or two ago for the first time. I remember when I first tried them soon after I bought them, they tasted a little off – when compared to the memory of the taste of them in a macadamia-white-chocolate cookie. Mom didn't like them either.
Now, a few years later, I thought to just heat up a few in the oven. And, when I ate a few, there was this very unpleasant sharp, bright, top-note bitter taste – perhaps a slight hint of sour that gave it that bright taste. It also had this slightly sticky feel akin to that "oil tar" residue you get on your range hood when you fry a lot.
Is this normal?

After one or two years, your macadamia nuts are almost certainly rancid or moldy, probably both, particularly if their taste was “off” at the beginning. Note that the high fat content limits their shelf life, particularly if the packaging was opened. Your taste buds gave you the right warning signs, neither bitter nor sour are expected flavors for macadamias, they indicate something different
Please discard them.

This is completely right. Once opened many nuts should be refrigerated, they last much longer that way.

@GdD I've had good results with almost every nut (cashew, "almond", walnut, pine nut, (salted) pistachio, peacan) except macadamia nut with regard to dry storage at room temperature. I noted that macadamia nuts are the only nuts that had an expiry date on the bag.
Thanks for input!
